# Table whose columns are random samples from an original column

Tags: sql, random, sample

I have numerical data ​​related to clinical information from people with a particular disease recorded in an specific column ('Lab') from Table A.

I need to get a Table B with 30 rows and 50 columns.

The columns of Table B should be random samples from the values ​​contained in column 'Lab' (nearly 3300 registers).

I am able to get a table with **one** column using:

```
SELECT Lab FROM Table_A sample (1) WHERE Lab IS NOT NULL;
```

Is it possible make a query using the `SELECT` command that results in Table B with all its 50 columns without the need of getting its columns one by one?

Comment: Let me see if I understand your question correctly: table `A` has 3300 rows, each has column called `Lab`; you want to create table `B` with 1500 values from `A.Lab`, drawn at random and organized into a 30x50 matrix? Also what vendor are you using, SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `RAND` operator with `ORDER BY`, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_A ORDER BY RAND( ) LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: will this return 50 columns?

Comment: This will return all the columns from Table A, if I understood correctly your question, you have 50 columns and 3300 rows in Table A?